# Loops that find if a server name contains certain letters, sets those to reboot on certain day of the week

Tags: powershell

I have the following code, but not sure I am thinking of solution properly. I take an array of server names, and want to find if there are servers that contain the characters 'as01'. If so, then 'as01a' will start rebooting on saturday, 'as01b' will reboot on sunday, then all the rest of the servers, that do not contain 'as01' will be randomized over the rest of the week.

```
   foreach($server in $servers){
       if ( $server -like '*as01*') {
       $i=6                     #set reboot to start on saturday
       set-xaworkergroup $([DayofWeek]($i++%7)) -servernames $_ 
       }
       else{ set-xaworkergroup $([DayofWeek]($i++%7)) -servernames $_ }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$i=0
$j=0

$servers = &{$args} as01a as01b as01c as02 as03 as04 as05 as06 as07 as08

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  if ($server -like '*as01*')
    { "$server reboots on $([DayOfWeek](0,6)[$i++%2])" }

  else { "$server reboots on $([DayOfWeek](1..5)[$j++%5])" }
}

as01a reboots on Sunday
as01b reboots on Saturday
as01c reboots on Sunday
as02 reboots on Monday
as03 reboots on Tuesday
as04 reboots on Wednesday
as05 reboots on Thursday
as06 reboots on Friday
as07 reboots on Monday
as08 reboots on Tuesday
```